# How to filter and append elements from a list onto a dictionary containing three lists: Uppercase, lowercase and numbers

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

I have a list `[2,'j','K','o',6,'x',5,'A',3.2]` and would like to filter out elements in uppercase, lowercase and numbers and place them in a dictionary with the lists
`{'numbers': \[\],'uppercase': \[\],'lowercase': \[\]}` 
respectively.

I am having trouble assigning the integer values to a list as it keeps showing an error.

Comment: what is the trouble you are having? iterating over the list is simple enough `for item in my_list:` then you test each `item` to see if its a number, a lower case letter or an uppercase letter. to test if its a number you can do `type(item) in [int, float]`. to test if its a a letter you can use `item in string.ascii_lowercase` or `item in string.ascii_uppercase` (you need to `import string`)

Comment: Hi, I tried the code and it works perfectly thanks. I was having a problem isolating integers within the list but the type(item) in [int, float] solves this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would solve the problem.

```py
import string


mylist = [2,'j','K','o',6,'x',5,'A',3.2]

# make empty lists
numbers = []
lowercase = []
uppercase = []

# test the cases
for i in mylist:
    if type(i) in [int,float]:
        numbers.append(i)
    
    elif i in string.ascii_lowercase:
        lowercase.append(i)

    elif i in string.ascii_uppercase:
        uppercase.append(i)

# put into a dict
d = {'numbers':numbers, 'lowercase':lowercase, 'uppercase':uppercase}

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{'numbers': [2, 6, 5, 3.2], 'lowercase': ['j', 'o', 'x'], 'uppercase': ['K', 'A']}
```